# What happens to my Ubuntu when I upgrade Windows?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, dual-boot, windows

If I am only upgrading my Windows partition from Vista to 7 will it erase my entire drive and I will have to reinstall Ubuntu as it would if I fresh installed it?

I currently have 12.04 and Vista installed on separate partitions on the same hard drive.
If it merely eliminates Grub I know how to reinstall that.

Comment: Related: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are installing 7, you can select the partitions for the system. If you do not erase/format the Ubuntu partition, then everything should be fine.

One thing could be a problem: Windows will override the bootloader, so grub will be gone if it's on the same partition. If you start your system after the Win 7 installation, probably Windows 7 will boot without any other options -> so you cannot start your Ubuntu. But that's fine, you just have to reinstall grub. The easiest way should be using boot-repair

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Okay thank you, So it will not erase the entire drive as if it were a fresh install.